# Eclipse CDT project temporary files

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

What files can be safely removed from CDT project and workspace before archiving or saving in a source control system?
Having MSVC experience, I tried to remove Debug and Release directories, this was really bad idea :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using an Eclipse plug-in for your version control system of choice? They seem to take care of everything (at least in my experience with the CVS and Mercurial plugins). If not, you'll need to tell Eclipse to refresh pretty much your whole project whenever you've interacted with version control.

The contents of the Debug and Release directories should all be autogenerated. If they're not, something's wrong.

Rather than what you can delete, turn it around and consider what you need to keep:

- .project, .cproject and (if it exists) .settings
- Your source directories
- Your include directories
- Any other human-created files at the top level e.g. Changelog, documentation

It may also be worthwhile looking inside the .metadata directory in your workspace root; for example, any launch configurations you have created are stored by default in .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/ . (Although I have seen them inside project directories from time to time.)

Comment: I am working with Ubuntu installed with Wubi on Windows computer. My main working environment is Windows, MSVC and Visual SourceSafe. Some of projects should be cross-platform, so I keep them on the Windows drive, and access them from Ubuntu, building Eclipse CDT projects parallel to MSVC projects.
So, I cannot use CVS features and need to make manual cleanup.
I will make additional trial with Debug and Release directories, thank you.

Comment: The problem is solved. Debug and Release directory can be removed. I found that normal Build command executed from the Eclipse fails after this, but Clean command succeeds. Eclipse doesn't like when some action with project files is done outside of it.
Thank you for your help.